# Is there any way to use iOS 14 SDK in Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios14

I would like make code changes for iOS14 but I don't want to upgrade to Xcode 12. Any work arounds can solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: use both Xcode 11, and Xcode 12

Comment: this is quite a repeating question every time a new iOS version is released. You cannot use old Xcode for new iOS version. Also, **always** use beta Xcode for beta iOS version. Don't mix up with production environment

Answer (score 1):

You have to download xcode 12 to support iOS14.
Xcode 12 support for iOS14.

See this documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-beta-release-notes